# group records from table 2 according to value of column of table1

Tags: mysql

I have two tables say table1 and table2 now i want to group all results from table2 according to a column from table1. What should be the query for this.

table2:
planId

30
32
36

table1

userplan_id        groupno
30                   1111 
32                   1111
36                   2222

now put all records from talbe2 according to groupno of talbe1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the question correctly, tough:

```
SELECT table2.planId,table1.groupno FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 WHERE table2.planId=table1.userplan_id
```